# Dateadd and datediff get last day in month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand why this query do the trick for february every year but not for the months with 31 days? I get 30 days for every months except february. Can Anyone explain it to me?

```
SELECT  dateadd( mm, -240 + 22, DATEADD(mm, 1 + DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) AS n
```

I use the code above cause I need to put in a number in the place for 22 to get different dates. I use it like a calender function with the last date for every month.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest variant is this:

```
DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010131')
```

Which basically says `DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE())` - how many (whole) months have elapsed since January 2001? And then adds that whole number of months onto the 31st January 2001. But when adding months, [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) will truncate the days portion if no such day exists in that month - so 31 gets rounded down to 30, 29 or 28, as appropriate.

The two dates picked above are arbitrary - all we needed to use was any month with 31 days in it.

---

If you need to vary which month you get (rather than the current month), you should be able to adjust this value just by adding or subtracting values here:

```
DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()) + N,'20010131')
```

Where `N` allows you to adjust which month is interesting to you (relative to the current month)

---

This code:

```
DATEADD(mm, 1 + DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

In the original question is another way of obtaining "the last day of the current month"<sup>1</sup> - and gets the same rounding behaviour described above. So if you run that code in April (today) it's get 30th April. If you then apply a further `DATEADD()` operation to that date, as in the question, then it can never restore itself back to the 31st.

If you use the original question code in February, it'll behave even worse. So a key aspect to getting any code like this to work correctly is to only use `DATEADD` *once*, to get to the final correct month, and where the rounding behaviour will actually be to your benefit.

<sup>1</sup>In my opinion, less readably so. I don't understand *why* people are such fans of the shortened date portion specifiers, nor why they'd prefer to use magic numbers such as the final `-1` actually meaning 31st December 1899.

Comment: You're right.The question is why it return 30 days for every months except february but not get the last day of month.

Comment: @AngusChung - because the OPs code is trying to do something similar but unfortunately, it's based around the *current* month rather than one known to be 31 days long and so the problem with the OPs code will persist for another 22 days and then start working as expected once it becomes May.

Comment: Thanks for good answer....I tried to change my code like this and now it seems to work with 31 and 30 days for actual month. But I dont understand why?                                                                                 SELECT  dateadd( mm, -240 + 22, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) AS n Can Anyone explain why? And does it work or am I wrong?

Comment: @Mcol - I try to address that in the third section of my answer. Your attempt first finds the last day of the *current* month, and *then* subtracts more months. We're in April so you get 30th April and then subtract a number of months from it. If you we're running this code next month, it would *appear* to work just fine (until June).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Current_Timestamp As today
     , DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, Current_Timestamp), 0) As first_of_current_month
     , DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, Current_Timestamp) + 1, 0) As first_of_next_month
     , DateAdd(dd, -1, DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, Current_Timestamp) + 1, 0)) As last_of_current_month
;
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining how your code works.  Just posting code does not make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it the following way.

First, get the first day of the current month:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Then, get the first day of the next month adding a month to previously obtained date:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())) AS DATE)
```

Finally, get the last day of current month as the day before the first day of the next month:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))) AS DATE)
```